# Listen for iOS screen capture event

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, triggers, listeners

Is there was a way to listen for the screen capture event on an iDevice?

**Logic:**

1. User takes a screen capture using the 'Power' plus 'Home' button combination.
2. Event is triggered and the listening application loads.
3. Application modifies captured image and exits.

The application could also listen for a *save to camera roll event*, as this will allow for the same types of modification.

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this directly... there is a bit of a workaround though explained here: 
http://tumblr.jeremyjohnstone.com/post/38503925370/how-to-detect-screenshots-on-ios-like-snapchat